# Losing background colour when focus is lost on a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have a QTableView in an existing product.  I have changed it to use a grey background for rows that can't be edited.  But, when the table loses focus, QT will change the background colour to grey.  I've found quite a few things on the internet to try but had no luck.

The closest I've got to anything is by setting the palette on the editor created in createEditor.  I've had no luck when setting the palette of the QTableView itself.  When the table loses focus, I see the test colour I've used (yellow) flash briefly before going grey.

I've been playing with the frozencolumn example provided with QT Creator but had less luck there as there's no editor.

```
  QPalette p = frozenTableView->palette();
  p.setColor(QPalette::Active, QPalette::Highlight, Qt::darkGreen);
  p.setColor(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::Highlight, Qt::green);
  p.setColor(QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::Highlight, Qt::yellow);
  p.setColor(QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::HighlightedText, Qt::darkYellow);
  frozenTableView->setPalette(p);
```

or

```
frozenTableView->setStyleSheet("QTableView { border: none;"
                                     "background-color: #8EDE21;"
                                     "selection-background-color: #999}"
      "QTableView:!active {"
                                     "selection-background-color: yellow;"
                                         "selection-color: yellow"
                                     );
```

Anything else I could try?  It's like QT is calling setPalette() when the focus is lost and undoing anything I manage to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using frozenTableWidget for testing is perhaps a bit confusing as it's a combination of 2 QTableWidgets.

```
   // QPalette p = frozenTableView->palette();
   QPalette p = palette();
   p.setColor(QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::Highlight, p.color(QPalette::Active, QPalette::Base));
   setPalette(p);
```

This removes the highlighted colour when focus is lost, if that's what you're after?